# Enabled the wp-multisite functionality leaves me in aproblem.

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I've enabled the wp-network site function, put the rule in wp-config.php and also modified the .htaccess file and enabled the subdomains. The subdomains working fine but the plugins tab from wp-admin panel is not showing up. I can activate or deactive the plugins due to this and also subdomain sites dashboards not showing.

Comment: Not programming related, suitable to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, inspect elements in dashboard and see if there is any problems in the console, and try to solve it if exists.
Second, Log out, clear your browser cache and cookies, restart your browser and take another look.
 If you still don't see it, and you think you are logged in as an administrator, go to users > all users and see what it lists as the "role" for your username.
That's the far I know without seeing the issue.